# Is it possible to get events when someone calls text() or html() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events

I need to know when the content of a DOM node changes. Luckily, I can be sure that all these changes will happen by a call to `.text(val)` or `.html(val)`.

Is it possible to make jQuery send events when these two functions are called?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't bind events to text and html changes.  Why not bind to whatever is triggering the DOM node changes?

Comment: As above.  Alternatively, create your own functions for setting `.text(val)` and `.html(val)` and have them do what the event handlers would do.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: There is no single place/event which triggers the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TXMZT/6/)**

You could overload the `.text()` (or any jQuery method) like so, and save anything that has been changed in a logging **Class** we can make.  Here's the basic class below.

```
var textLogger = new (function textChangeLog () {  
  this.logArray = [];

  this.add = function (item) {
    this.logArray.push(item);
  };

  this.displayLog = function (index) {
    if (typeof index === 'number') { console.log( this.logArray[index] ); }
    else { console.log( this.logArray ); }
  };
})();
```

Now we override the current `.text()` and add our few additions. The **logging class**, and a callback function (in case you wanted more functionality)

```
$.fn.oldText = $.fn.text; 
// ** NOTE: At any point you can just use $('body').oldText('change it');
// to by pass any of the below changes / overrides to .text()

$.fn.text = function (str, funcEvent) {
  try {
    // Let's log anything that's being changed in our textLogger class Array
    textLogger.add($(this));

    // call the original .text()
    $(this).oldText(str); 

    // the optional event you passed in
    var callbackFunc = typeof funcEvent !== 'undefined' ? funcEvent : function () { };
    callbackFunc(); 
  }
  catch(e) { console.log(e); }
};
```

Now we do some example useage, and then we do **textLogger.displayLog()** to see our results in the console. You'll see the entire jQuery selector / context / IDs in there, in an Array.

```
$('div').text('here');
$('#anotherExample').text('we changed this too!');

textLogger.displayLog();

$('#cbTest').text('blah', function () { console.log('callback!'); });
```

**EDIT** Updated the jsFiddle to show how to trigger / respond to a custom event when a text changes.

Comment: Accepted for biggest effort :-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla Thank you! I was curious too actually, feel like I might use this in certain situations myself :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really needed to accomplish this, you could consider [monkey-patching](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/) jQuery. The basic gist **EDITED - taken from the referenced link**:

```
(function($){
   // store original reference to the method
   var _old = $.fn.text;

   $.fn.text = function(text){
      // modifications go here       
      return _old.apply(this,arguments);
   };
})(jQuery);
```

It's pretty heavy-handed, so I'd only consider it if it's the only way to get what you need, and you'd have to be pretty careful about jQuery API changes.

Comment: This won't work, you are setting the $.fn.originalText twice, and not setting the `this` / context.

Comment: was just a rough gist. Full implementation of a working one is in the link.

Comment: Edited the answer to bind `this` properly

Comment: There it is! The other way I showed in my answer below where ` $(this).oldText(str);` where I leave `$.fn.oldText = $.fn.text;` just incase you ever want to outright use the old one, and *bypass* this new method. Always a good back-up.

Answer (score 2):

You could extend the jQuery functions `text()` and `html()`.
I've found this somewhere (I am sorry that I don't have the source, someone please edit if you know who should have the credit for it) and it works like a charm for me

```
(function ($) {
    var originalHtmlFunction = $.fn.html;
    $.fn.html = function (value) {
        if (typeof value != 'undefined') {
                var jqObj = originalHtmlFunction.call(this, value);
                // Do your magic here
                return jqObj;
        }
        else {
            return originalHtmlFunction.call(this, value);
        }
    };

    var originalTextFunction = $.fn.text;
    $.fn.text = function (value) {
        if (typeof value != 'undefined') {
                var jqObj = originalTextFunction.call(this, value);
                // Do your magic here
                return jqObj;
        }
        else {
            return originalTextFunction.call(this,value);
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, though depending on how you use said methods it may not be efficient.

```
$.each(["text","html"], function(i,method) {
    var oldMethod = $.fn[method];
    $.fn[method] = function(){
        this.trigger(method+"change");
        oldMethod.apply(this,arguments);
    };
});

// sample usage:
$("#someelement").on("textchange",function(){
    alert("Text Change!");
}).text("Foobar");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CZCKq/